# Logic to get rows for a particular date when the day starts at 12pm and ends at 2am next day

Tags: database

I have a table of orders where orders are stored with the timestamp of when the order was created. The restaurant shift starts from 12:00 PM noon and ends at 2:00 AM the next day (this is adjustable and they can changed the shift timings).

Now, I want a reporting listing all the orders for the current day but starting from 12:00 PM and I also want the orders for 2 hours of the next day as well.

There are 3 scenarios here:

1. The user sees the report at 5:00 AM. He should see 0 orders.
2. The user sees the report at 6:00 PM. He should see all the orders for that day starting from 12:00 PM.
3. The user sees the report at 1:00 AM. He should see all the orders for today starting from 12:00 in the night + the orders for yesterday starting from 12:00 PM

How can I implement this logic?
Remember that the shift timings are flexible and can also start and ends the same day i.e. 9:00 AM - 11:00 PM

Comment: Have you tried to implement the logic yourself?

Comment: @IanKemp yes 

My query would be:
"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date > today + 12PM and date < tomorrow + 2AM"

This satisfies case #1 and #2 but fails for #3

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a quick answer but when I didn't get any reply, I decided to do it myself

We will create shift divisions. If a shift is spread over 2 days (12pm to 2am), we'll have 2 divisions otherwise we'll have only 1 division. The divisions will be stored in an array.

We will loop through the divisions and see if the current hour falls in any of the divisions.

Here is the code I wrote (Node.js):

```
static getOutletCurrentDateRange(brand: Brand, outlet: Outlet): DateRange {
    let divisions: ShiftDivision[] = [];
    if (outlet.endTime > 24) {
        divisions.push({ start: outlet.startTime, end: 24 });
        divisions.push({ start: 24, end: outlet.endTime });
    }
    else {
        divisions.push({ start: outlet.startTime, end: outlet.endTime });
    }
    console.log("divisions: ", divisions);
    let current = moment().hour() + (brand.utcDifference || 300)/60;
    if (current > 23) {
        current = current - 24;
    }
    console.log("current", current);
    let index = 0;
    let found = false;
    while (!found && index < divisions.length) {
        if (current >= divisions[index].start && current <= divisions[index].end) {
            console.log("found at index", index);
            found = true;
        }
        else {
            index++;
        }
        current += 24;
    }
    if (!found) {
        return { start: null, end: null }
    }
    let startDate = moment();
    startDate.minute(0);
    startDate.second(0);
    let endDate = moment();
    endDate.minute(0);
    endDate.second(0);
    if (index == 0) {
        console.log("yes 0");
        console.log(divisions.length);
        startDate.hour(divisions[0].start);
        if (divisions.length > 1) {
            endDate.hour(divisions[1].end);
        }
        else {
            endDate.hour(divisions[0].end);
        }
    }
    if (index == 1) {
        console.log("yes 1");
        startDate.hour(divisions[0].start);
        endDate = endDate.add(1, "days");
        endDate.hour(divisions[1].end);

    }
    startDate.minutes(-1 * (brand.utcDifference || 300));
    endDate.minutes(-1 * (brand.utcDifference || 300));
    console.log("here", startDate, endDate);
    return { start: startDate, end: endDate };
}
```

If anyone have a better solution or can improve this solution, he's more than welcomed :)